# Loading 5,000 Images in recycler view using glide

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, mediastore

I was following Google Storage Samples guide and tried to implement [this MediaStore](https://github.com/android/storage-samples/tree/master/MediaStore/app/src/main/java/com/android/samples/mediastore) guide in java, as the provided one is written in Kotiln. I compiled and ran provided code and it works fine, I have almost 5,000+ images on my device. The sample provided by google displays them in a RecyclerView, and images are loaded using glide.

But, when I implemented similar in java, the RecyclerView is super slow, you hardly scroll and then after some while app stops. I am definitely missing something.

**Code Sample by Google [Kotlin]**

```
private inner class GalleryAdapter(val onClick: (MediaStoreImage) -> Unit) :
        ListAdapter<MediaStoreImage, ImageViewHolder>(MediaStoreImage.DiffCallback) {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImageViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_layout, parent, false)
            return ImageViewHolder(view, onClick)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val mediaStoreImage = getItem(position)
            holder.rootView.tag = mediaStoreImage

            Glide.with(holder.imageView)
                .load(mediaStoreImage.contentUri)
                .thumbnail(0.33f)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView)
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Basic [RecyclerView.ViewHolder] for our gallery.
 */
private class ImageViewHolder(view: View, onClick: (MediaStoreImage) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val rootView = view
    val imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image)

    init {
        imageView.setOnClickListener {
            val image = rootView.tag as? MediaStoreImage ?: return@setOnClickListener
            onClick(image)
        }
    }
}
```

**MY Code [Java]**

**Adapter**

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {


    class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private ImageView imageView;
        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        }
    }

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Picture> pictures;


    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Picture> pictures) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.pictures = pictures;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.single_image_view, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Picture p = pictures.get(position);
        Glide.with(holder.imageView)
                .load(p.getUri())
                .thumbnail(0.33f)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pictures.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: did u try mRecyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: @wahdat Kashmiri, just did. It's still the same.

Comment: Is it there any error occur when app close?

Comment: Use ListAdapter in Your Java code as well

Comment: You are not using pagination